# Wordplay concerning the Ayin and the Aleph in Gemara

Tags: talmud-gemara, pronunciation, aleph-bet-letters, story-identification

I remember hearing about some interesting statements made about those that fail to distinguish pronunciation between the ayin and the aleph. An example was given in gemara about why such a distinction is important to make when speaking Hebrew and was made with wordplay where a sentence could be fundamentally changed if the two letters are confused. I think it went along the lines of confusing axing someone (killing them) with giving them dates.

Does anyone here possibly know what I may be misremembering?

Comment: It's not what you're looking for, but [Shabbos 103b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=103b&format=pdf) is related.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22889/759

Comment: Not sure. But maybe maasarot first Perek second Mishnah, hate'einim misheyavchilu ( one is obligated to tithe figs when they begin to ripen) where if you transpose the bet and Chet you get misheyachvilu, when they are chovel ( injure ) someone. Would need to see if a Gemara makes that switch and joke.

Comment: אבד vs. עבד (as in והיה אם שמוע [which I accidentally just tried to spell with an א even though I distinguish between the two phonemes]). The shoresh אבד relates to dying whereas the shoresh עבד relates to serving (or worshipping).

Comment: perhaps your thinking about http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=53b&format=text

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're thinking of Berachos 32a

> ואמר רבי אלעזר משה הטיח דברים כלפי מעלה שנאמר {במדבר יא-ב} ויתפלל משה אל ה' אל תקרי אל ה' אלא על ה' שכן דבי רבי אליעזר בן יעקב קורין לאלפין עיינין ולעיינין אלפין

Answer (score 0):

In mseches Megillah daf 24B it says something similar about confusing an א and an ע, but not about killing a person. Very funny Gemara!

Comment: Please edit in the main points of the gemoro that you quote.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, I haven't learned this gemora, but I believe it references the distinction between אבד, perish, vs. עבד, serve/labour

Answer (score 0):

> YEBAMOT 22B
>
> מי שיש לו בן מ"מ פוטר וכו':  מכל מקום לאתויי מאי אמר רב יהודה לאיתויי ממזר מאי טעמא דאמר קרא (דברים כה) ובן **אין לו עיין עליו**: ‏
>
> 35B
>
> יתמר החולץ **למעוברת והפילה** רבי יוחנן אמר אינה צריכה חליצה מן האחין ר"ל אמר **צריכה חליצה** מן האחין ר' יוחנן אמר א"צ חליצה מן האחין חליצת מעוברת שמה חליצה וביאת מעוברת שמה ביאה ור"ל אמר צריכה חליצה מן האחין חליצת מעוברת לא שמה חליצה וביאת מעוברת לא שמה ביאה במאי קמפלגי איבעית אימא קרא ואיבעית אימא סברא איבעית אימא סברא רבי יוחנן סבר אם יבא אליהו ויאמר דהא דאיעברא מפולי מפלה מי לאו בת חליצה ויבום היא השתא נמי תגלי מילתא למפרע ור"ל אמר תגלי מילתא למפרע לא אמרינן ואיבעית אימא קרא רבי יוחנן סבר (דברים כה) ובן **אין לו** אמר רחמנא והא לית ליה **ור"ל סבר ובן אין לו עיין** ‏
>
> KIDDUSHIN 4A
>
> אין כסף אלו ימי נערות אמר רבינא אם כן לימא קרא אן כסף מאי אין כסף אין כסף לאדון זה אבל יש כסף לאדון אחר ומאן ניהו אב וממאי דדרשינן הכי דתניא (ויקרא כב) וזרע **אין לה** אין לי אלא זרעה זרע זרעה מנין ת"ל זרע אין לה **עיין לה** ואין לי אלא זרע כשר זרע פסול מנין ת"ל זרע אין לה עיין לה והא אפיקתיה לזרע זרעה זרע זרעה  ‏ לא איצטריך קרא דבני בנים הרי הן כבנים כי איצטריך קרא לזרע פסול ‏

All this Gemarot "joke" between Ein and Ayien. the joke may be explained in diverse manner, but the basis is changing between "Aleph" and "Ayin".

Comment: I think your sources are the opposite of what the OP wants. You bring sources where ayin and aleph are interchangeable through derasha. The OP seeks a gemara where they must not be interchanged.

Comment: @user6591 right this is difference btween the pshat reading and the drash

Comment: @user6591 the title is wodplay, the drashot are not wordplay in this case? I am ready to suppress the post but I am not sure that the examples are not relevant wordplay.

Comment: There is also Ktonet or bealef and Ayin but I found this in Midrash and not in Gemara

Comment: I wasn't focusing on the fact that it is a drasha. My point was that you bring cases where it is ok and good to change one letter to the other. The OP wants a case where chazzal point out that it is bad to change one to the other

Comment: In my guess also mention a gemara that switches one to the other but the gemara paints it in a bad light

Comment: your example in el hashem is equivalent to ein and ayen. the nusach al tikre is not a real argument. but I dont want to convince you but to explain why I maintain my post

Comment: @user6591 but your answer is better!